# Returning Value of Array 2D php

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array, html-table

Sorry, please i need some help, i've a problem in returning Multidimensional value array in CodeIgniter. I've multidimensional array value in model to return in view. My source code look like below.

This is my model

```
$value1 = array();
$value2 = array();
$value = array(
         $value1,
         $value2
         );
return $value;
```

This is my view

```
foreach($get_value as $row){
     echo " <td>$row</td> ";
}
```

In this case, i've no sql connection, the value of array is float type. Thanks, your answer might can help me. Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you value 1&2

```
foreach($get_value as $row){
     echo " <td>$row[0]</td> <td>$row[1]</td> ";
}
```

Comment: @NoegyEgiNoviyansah glad it works for you :) feel free to accept if it answers the question for you. this will result in +2 rep for you. see: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/321521)